# Apache log file x-forwarded-for CSV manipulation

Tags: apache-http-server, logging, headers

I'm logging x-forwarded-for with the `%{X-FORWARDED-FOR}i` formatter.  However, there are times when the X-Forwarded-For header is getting CSV'd (based on a client's setup):

```
X-Forwarded-For: 66.66.66.66, 123.123.123.123
```

Which shows up in the log file as the above CSV'd IP's.

Is there any way to configure Apache so that I'm only logging the left-most IP address?  It's the only one I ever care about.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You can do it using a regex to extract the left-most IP:

```
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "^(\d{1,3}+\.\d{1,3}+\.\d{1,3}+\.\d{1,3}+).*" XFFCLIENTIP=$1
```

Note the use of **$1** to set the XFFCLIENTIP environment variable to hold the contents of the first group in the regex (in the parentheses)
Then you can define a log format that uses the variable: this example is one we use internally at nearmap.com, so it logs extra information, but the bit you want is the **%{XFFCLIENTIP}e** at the beginning.  Note the **env=XFFCLIENTIP** at the end of the line, which means this format is only used if the environment variable is set.

```
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log "%{XFFCLIENTIP}e \"%{session}C\" \"%{nearmapuid}C\" %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\"" env=XFFCLIENTIP
```